# Mail function is not working in PHP

Tags: email, php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //if "email" is filled out, proceed

    $name=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $phone=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);

    $to = "admin@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Customer Intrested";
    $message = "Buyer Information and Intrested in land.";
    $message.= "Customer Name :".$name."\n";
    $message.= "Customer Phone :".$phone."\n";  

    $mail=mail($to, "Subject: $subject",$message );
    if($mail){
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "failed."; 
    }
?>
```

I am using the above code to send email..but i am unable to get the result..it always showing the "Thank you message"..

I can able to get the values of name and phone.

How to fix this Problem?

Comment: where are you run this code offline or online?

Comment: if you have set mail setting in php.ini, check your junk mails

Comment: @renishkhunt i am running this code on online

Comment: @HarishSingh I checked the span folder also..but not getting the mail

Comment: @PHPCoder your email function working.

Comment: @Chinmay But why it is showing "failed" on server? any suggesstions

Comment: Did you try setting the header **$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com';** **mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);**

Comment: hey you missed `}` in this code. put `}` before `?>`

Comment: @ThusithaSumanadasa oh!! i missed it in the question but it is present in my code... Finally i got answer... it's the server problem not the code....

Comment: @PHPCoder what was the issue with the server?

Comment: @user2363025 The issue is the cpanel sever accept to send only to cpanel emails.. or else it will send the mails when we use cpanel email as "from" in the mail function then only it allowes to send and we have changed the server, now the problem solved.. Thanks for all..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
mail($to, "Subject: $subject",$message );
echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
```

instead of this ,first check if the mail is sent

```
$mail=mail($to, "Subject: $subject",$message );
if($mail){
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
}else{
  echo "Mail sending failed."; 
}
```

By this actually u can know whether your mail function in working or not

if it is not working.the problem can be with SMTP settings in your localhost

enable errors in php if not enabled using

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

Comment: if i am using if($mail)condition it shows the mail sending failed..How to correct it?

Comment: but it shows success in localhost

Answer (score 2):

```
// message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
```

for more help:http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Comment: I'd recommend never using w3schools