# Mail Function was not working

Tags: php

Mail function was not working, but i am getting success message,but mail was not sent My code is following ,but this code working fine on another one server i can't identify the problem any solution for in this problem.........?

```
    <?php
include("conn.php");

if(isset($_REQUEST["mmailid"]))
{
     $to=$_REQUEST["mmailid"];
$rs=mysql_query("select mmailid,mpass,mname from memtb where mmailid='$to'");

  $rd1=mysql_num_rows($rs);
    if($rd1>0)
    {
        $rd=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
             $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
             $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
             $headers .= 'Bcc: itstephen34@gmail.com' . "\r\n";


        $body="<table border=5 style='border-color:blue'><p><h3><img src='http://www.stephenraj.in/images/logo.jpg' alt='stephen Logo' /></h3></p><p>Dear " . $rd[2] . ",</p><p> &nbsp; &nbsp; Your Password is : " . $rd[1] . " .</p><p>" . "<p><h1>&nbsp;</h1></p><p>SUPPORT Team</p><p>CHANDRASTORE</p></table>";

         ini_set("SMTP","localhost");
         ini_set("sendmail_from","info@stephenraj.in");

        $mail=mail($to,"Stephen Password Recovery  MAIL",$body,$headers);
        //mail($tomailid,"Stephen Registration Confirmation MAIL",$body,$headers);
        if(isset($mail))
        {
        echo "Your Password Was Sent To Your Mail";
        // echo $rd[2].$rd[1];
        }
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid Mail ID'
}


?>
```

Comment: **Security Note:** don't send passwords in plain-text!

Comment: maybe this could help :

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297703/mail-function-is-not-working-in-php>

Comment: Is the mail servre configured on your server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check with your hosting server..when ever we write a mail it will send through from our server first if your server to another doesn't have privilege or fire wall wont send.so check with your server hosting once

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the problem i faced a while ago. I discovered in my case that the problem was with the **firewall** of the server. I contacted the server admin and he did things right. Maybe this is the same problem you are facing.

Comment: Acyut : thanks for your suggestion i will be do that