# php mail() function is not working for sending a simple mail

Tags: php

Now I tried to send mails through php mail function for a application . But the problem is , when I send a mail through this result is given as 'Message has sent'
but actually I couldn't get any mails from this .

This is my `php` code ,

```
<?php
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone']; 
        $message=$_POST['message'];

        $to='yyyy222@xxx.com';
        $subject='New mail';
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers='From : '.$email."r\n".
                 'Reply-To : '.$email."r\n";
        echo 'Starting send mail';
        echo '<br>';
        $sent=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        if(!$sent){
            echo 'There are problems in sending mails  <br>';
        }else{
            echo 'Message has sent';
            echo '<br>';
        }       
        echo 'Mail sent';
        echo '<br>';
   ?>
```

Today is my first day in learning php . And I would like learn more .

Comment: Check the SMTP settings. check is it on.

Comment: 1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803994/php-mail-not-working-for-some-reason 2] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297703/mail-function-is-not-working-in-php 3] 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail Please refer this URLs

Comment: @Jack : Thank you jack . I'll try the urls .

Comment: @SantoshJagtap PHP `mail()` doesn't need SMTP settings

Comment: Are you on a local server? Do you have any mail server installed?

Comment: @Barrier are you running on web server or localhost? PHP `mail()` doesn't work in localhost

Comment: I would advise you use a reliable library like PHPMailer you will have to do a lot less manual manipulation https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Comment: @Nikko : I run this on localhost .

Comment: @Barrier well, it would never work. try to use PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.

Comment: @Nikko : Ok nikko , I'll use it from this moment .

Answer (score 1):

You're third $headers line is missing the period.

```
$headers='From : '.$email."r\n".
                 'Reply-To : '.$email."r\n";
```

This is what you have ^^ - This is what you should have:

```
$headers .= 'From : '.$email."r\n".
                 'Reply-To : '.$email."r\n";
```

Comment: check again your backslash. should be `\r\n`

Comment: Interestingly if you're using a Postfix mail server it expects the line terminators in the header to be provided in the format native to the OS ... so `PHP_EOL`  rather than `\r\n`.

Comment: @socialconquest : Thank you . and now I am trying this again .